# Threads exercise. Print alternately the ids of two distinct threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have to write a programme which creates 2 threads that print their own ID and then finish.
The threads must print their ID alternately (A, B, A, B, ...).

```
void *funct();
//void *functz();
//int functie=0;

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main(){
        int rc1, rc2;
        pthread_t thread1, thread2;

    if( (rc1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &funct, NULL)) )
        {
                printf("Eroare la creare thread: %d \n", rc1);
        }
        if( (rc2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &funct, NULL)) )
        {
                printf("Eroare la creare thread: %d \n", rc2);
        }
        pthread_join (thread1, NULL);
        pthread_join (thread2, NULL);

        return 0;
}

void *funct()
{
        int i;
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        for( i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
                printf("Thread ID: %li \n", pthread_self() );

        //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
        //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
        }
    //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
}
/*
void *functz()
{
        int i;
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        for( i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);

                printf("Thread ID: %li \n", pthread_self() );

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);    
       }
*/
```

As you can see, I have tried multiple strategies, but none of them was successful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Also: What do you mean by not successful? Did your compiler or linker give you an error (which one)?. Did the program crash at runtime (What did the debugger say)? Did it not print the correct output (Which output did it print)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ to be fair, debugging multithreaded programs is notoriously hard.

Comment: What synchronization primitives besides mutex do you know? How can you use them?

Comment: I think one Mutex, with a race condition could help... but it won't solve the problem properly... you might consider using a "conditional variable"... good luck!

Comment: @Arkadiy mutexes are perfectly fine for this problem. It is just a matter of how to juggle them.

Comment: There is no error. The actual problem is that the code prints alternatively, but not every time.

Comment: For example, now it prints the threads ids in the following order: A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,B,A,A,B,A,B ....

Comment: The 'classic' soulution for this uses two semaphores.  A single 'execute now' token is swapped between the threads, forcing them to run alternately.  Mutex is the wrong tool for this requirement, (why mutex is continually misused, I cannot understand).

Answer (score 0):

Forget mutex.

Use two semaphores, eg semRunA, initialized to 1 unit, and semRunB, initialized with 0 units.  Then swap around the one 'execution token':

thread A:

```
while(true){
  wait(semRunA);
  print(threadID);
  post(semRunB);
};
```

thread B:

```
while(true){
  wait(semRunB);
  print(threadID);
  post(semRunA);
};
```

See how easy it is when you use the correct synchronization objects?